# UK Visa for Freelancer Tuition Teacher

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I need some help regarding a UK Visitor visa. I am a private tuition teacher at an institute and we provide classes to under graduate students for various subjects and competitive exams, we are a group of teachers with each of us taking different subjects.

Payments are managed by a coordinator who is paid in the form of cash/paytm/transfer by students and then we are paid via a bank transfer based on number of students in our batch.

My question is - What documents should I submit to prove my employment apart from bank statements?

Comment: What documentation do you use to submit your tax return?

Comment: generally, bank statements only

Answer (score 3):

The [GOV guide to supporting documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk) states these are the documents you can provide to show you have funds available:

> - financial documents showing that you have sufficient funds available. These must clearly show that you have access to the funds, such as:
>
>   - bank statements
>   - building society book
>   - proof of earnings such as a letter from employer confirming employment details (start date of employment, salary, role, company contact details)

Bank statements should suffice, you can also provide a latter from your coordinator if you wish but this is not required.

Bank statements show you have a sustainable income and a suitable lifestyle and that you can support yourself.

For more information on why bank statements are important see this Travel.Se question:

- [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Answer (score 2):

Your employment contract and latest tax return should suffice.

See the section on ‘Provenance of Funds’ in [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

Comment: thanks for your response, last year tax return might not be reflecting the income as i started the batches in july last year , Do you think it would create issues ?

Comment: Explain it. Do not other-think about the amount of income. Check that you have funds for the travel, than it is clear you will not teach/work in UK, you are not a security concern, and that you will not overstay: these are the main points. Income helps to proof for the first and last point. But many people of other countries have less income then India but they can still visit UK.